# What commandline is used for Z3 in rise4fun?

Tags: z3

What are the command line options used for Z3 in rise4fun?
I can solve the following problem on the web but not on my local installations which include z3_4.3.2 z3_3.2 and others...

```
(declare-fun x () Int)
(assert-soft false) 
(assert-soft true)
(check-sat)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tutorial on optimization, that introduces the syntax you are using, 
says where the version comes from. These are new features being developed for optimization.
Normal features are otherwise the same between the online version and the unstable branch that we provide builds for.